# How to limit the number of results in an LDAP query

Tags: ldap, limit, adodb, word-2010

I'm programming an Office 2010 Word template that needs to interact with the Active Directory, to retrieve some user info. The user filling out the template can give some input for the search that is used to retrieve the AD info. 
I'm using the ADODB Recordset and Command to setup my query:

```
Public Function GetActiveDirectoryInfo(searchString As String) As Object
 Dim adoCommand, adoConnection, strBase, strFilter, strAttributes
 Dim strQuery, adoRecordset

 'remove user input asteriks
 searchString = Replace(searchString, "*", "")

 ' Setup ADO objects.
 Set adoCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
 Set adoConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
 adoConnection.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
 adoConnection.Open "Active Directory Provider"
 Set adoCommand.ActiveConnection = adoConnection

 strBase = "<LDAP://" & GLOBAL_LDAP_USER_OU & ">"

 ' Filter on user objects.
 strFilter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(|(sn=" & searchString & "*)(cn=" & searchString & "*)))"

 ' Comma delimited list of attribute values to retrieve.
 strAttributes = ACTIVE_DIRECTORY_FIELDS

 ' Construct the LDAP syntax query.
 strQuery = strBase & ";" & strFilter & ";" & strAttributes & ";OneLevel"
 adoCommand.CommandText = strQuery
 adoCommand.Properties("Page Size") = 10
 adoCommand.Properties("Timeout") = 30
 adoCommand.Properties("Cache Results") = False
 'adoCommand.Properties("Maximum Rows") = 10  'error: read only

 On Error GoTo err_NoConnection

 ' Run the query.
 Set adoRecordset = adoCommand.Execute

 Set foundItems = adoRecordset
 Debug.Print "Found : " & foundItems.RecordCount & " records"

  Exit Function

err_NoConnection:
  'in case of error: return <nothing>
  Debug.Print Err.description
  Set GetActiveDirectoryInfo = Nothing
End Function
```

THis function is part of a User Class in MS Word.

My question: how to prevent the user from retrieving thousands of records? I have been reading about paging, but that seems more like a network-load-thing than actually limiting the search results that will eventually get back to me.

I've tried several things but with no results. For instance setting the MaxRecords or Maximum Rows properties. Both give an error (non existing property for the first, and read only error for the second).

ANy ideas anyone.

MS Office 2010 dutch
ADO Objects 6.0

Thanx!

Comment: As per this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675268(v=vs.85).aspx>), `MaxRecords` is the way to do it. Please check the example linked in the above link to check that you have used it the correct way.

Comment: @HYS : your link results in a 'contents not found' (in dutch though)

Comment: Oops sorry. Try [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675268(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @HYS I'll give it a try tomorrow and get back to you

Comment: @HYS The code in the mentioned example works: it yields records without error. But I still get more than 10 records while using  adoRecordset.MaxRecords = 10
 
 adoRecordset.Open strQuery, adoConnection, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText

Comment: Ok, after looking around a bit more, looks like you may be running into [link]https://support.microsoft.com/kb/269361. Try the workaround mentioned.

Comment: @HYS It works like a charm! Took me some fiddling and code cleanup, but now it works. Very happy :) Could you post your link as a new entry so I can flag it as an anwser?

Comment: Thats great. I have added the entry. Add any additional details that you think will be helpful for others in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately `ADO MaxRecord` that limits the number of search results is not implemented for `ADsDSObject`. The link https://support.microsoft.com/kb/269361 details the workaround to solve the issue.

Comment: The link gives a 404 now.